# Cannot launch Hawtio

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

I am testing with apache camel on a newly installed linux ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine.
I followed the steps to install camel using jbang on the guide (https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-jbang.html). So far so good, I can create a initial hello world example and it runs. Only I cannot start hawtio.

I can start jolokia and its attached. Jolokia website is reachable.
Only when I try to start hawtio (via camel hawtio command) it reports:

```
Cannot launch Hawtio due to: io.hawt.embedded.Main
```

What could the reason be?

Comment: Can you try 3.20.4 release when its out later this week - we have some fixes on the way